# Is there a way to get in the left border using enumerate?

Tags: enumerate

When I write

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
\item blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
\end{enumerate}
```

I get [image]

Whereas, what I would like is to have

[image]

I know that I can get that using

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
\end{enumerate}
\noindent blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
\end{enumerate}
\noindent blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
```

but I was wondering if it would be possible directly without from

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
\item blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Take a look at  the `enumitem` package. `wide=\parindent` should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a list for this, unless you intend to nest them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcounter{myitem}

\newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{myitem}\par\vskip\itemsep\noindent
  \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\themyitem\hskip\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{myitem}{0}
\myitem blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
\myitem blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `wide=\parindent` and `font=\bfseries` from the `enumitem` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[wide=\parindent, font=\bfseries]
\item blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
\item blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```